# PCRE repetition based on captured number -- (\d)(.{\1})

Tags: regex, perl, pcre, julia

```
1xxx      captures x
2xxx      captures xx
3xxx      captures xxx
```

I thought maybe this simple pattern would work:

```
(\d)(.{\1})
```

But no.

I know this is easy in Perl, but I'm using PCRE in Julia which means it would be hard to embed code to change the expression on-the-fly.

Comment: You can't do that with PCRE.

Comment: `\1` means "match what the first set of parens captured".

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You mean the pattern doesn't work or it can't be done with any pattern? I know the pattern doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, you can't put a backreference inside a curly bracket quantifier.

Comment: Well, depending on the language you are using you could use a callback and check it. So you match using `(\d+)(x+)` and in the callback you check the length of group 2 and compare it to group 1.

Answer (score 5):

Note that regular expressions are usually compiled to a state machine before being executed, and are not naively interpreted.

Technically, `n Xn` (where *n* is a number and *X* a rule containing all characters) isn't a *regular language*. It isn't a *context-free* language, and isn't even a  *context-sensitive language*! (See the [Chomsky Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)). While PCRE regexes can match all all context-free languages (if expressed suitably), the engine can only match a very limited subset of context-sensitive languages. We have a big problem on our hand that can neither be solved by regular expressions nor regexes with all the PCRE extensions.

The solution here usually is to separate tokenization, parsing, and semantic validation when trying to parse some input. Here:

1. read the number (possibly using a regex)
2. read the following characters (possibly using a regex)
3. validate that the length of the character string is equal to the given number.

Obviously this isn't going to work in this specific case without implementing backtracking or similar strategies, so we will have to write a parser ourselves that can handle the input:

1. read the number (possibly using a regex)
2. then read that number of characters at that position (possibly using a `substr`-like function).

Regexes are awesome, but they are simply not the correct tool for every problem. Sometimes, writing the program yourself is easier.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done in general. For the particular example you gave, you can use the following:

```
1.{1}|2.{2}|3.{3}
```

If you have a long but fix list of numbers, you can generate the pattern programmatically.

Comment: was about to commit pretty much the same )) +1

Comment: Ha. It is a long but fixed list of the form NMMMMddd... where N gives the number of M digits which gives the length of data to capture. I think it would be a long programmatically-generated pattern.

Comment: Yeah, use your own parser. `my $len1 = substr($buf, 0, 1, ''); my $len2 = substr($buf, 0, $len1, '');  my $str = substr($buf, 0, $len2, '');` (plus some error checking).